# Why is my 'add to home screen' Web App Install Banner not showing up in my web app

Tags: html, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I've created a service-worker and `manifest.json` file in order to display an 'add to home screen' Web App Install Banner for Chrome Browser Users.

It is not working as intended.

Here is my `manifest.json` file

```
{
  "name": "MySite",
  "short_name": "Mysite",
  "start_url": "./?utm_source=homescreen",
  "icons": [{
      "src": "assets/cacheable/images/shortcut/120x120.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "assets/cacheable/images/shortcut/142x142.png",
      "sizes": "142x142",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "assets/cacheable/images/shortcut/192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "assets/cacheable/images/shortcut/192x192.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    }],
  "orientation": "portrait" ,
  "background_color": "#fff",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#fff"
}
```

Please let me know if I forgot to add anything?

Comment: Can you share service-worker file, because i am stuck there.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, let's check if your manifest fulfills the requirements for showing Web App Install Banners.

**Requirements:**

Full (*current*) requirements for showing Web App Install Banners are:

- Have a web app manifest file with:

  - a short_name
  - a name (used in the banner prompt)
  - a 144x144 png icon
  - a start_url that loads
- Is served over HTTPS (a requirement for using service worker).
- <s>Is visited at least twice, with at least five minutes between visits.</s>

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/app-install-banners/)

Okay, so for now let's assume this is all valid. Let's move on to testing.

**Testing:**

To test if you've installed it correctly, you can try the following steps:

1. Open Chrome DevTools,
2. Go to the **Application** panel
3. Go to the **Manifest** tab
4. Click **Add to homescreen**.

A prompt should now show on top of your browser asking if you want to add the URL to your things (on Chrome desktop).

**Troubleshooting:**

If after testing you are getting the following error in your console:

> No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest

Then please make sure that:

1. Your service worker is functioning properly and without errors, and
2. Your `start_url` matches an actual URL of your website that *loads*.

Else, you will never get the prompt to show!

**Additionally**,

Do note that users (and you!) can also add to the home screen manually through the the (Android) Chrome menu. It is not required to wait for the prompt! I add a lot of websites I tend to use daily to my homescreen, and I hardly ever see a banner!

** Do note that these requirements could change from time to time (they have before!). An update to 'Add to home screen' coming in 2017 has already been announced [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen)*

*** Also note that these requirements differ significantly from native app install prompts.***

Comment: It's on HTTPS because server-worker does not work over http. And I've already mention that what I describe met what you mentioned. And I've already tested that open chrome web dev tool and click on 'Add to home screen' butt and then my logo is displayed on screen. and google already mention that `that dialog will open second visit within 5 mins` but not showing for me.

Comment: Okay so do you want to check what the prompt looks like or do you want to check the functionality of opening your app as a web-app?

Comment: I want, `Add to Home Screen` button popup on my app as web-app.

Comment: When you follow the instructions in the above 4 steps, and click the **Add to homescreen**, do you get an error in the console? Something like: "Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest"?
Also, it _might_ be that you need to browse a bit before the actual prompt opens, I had that issue myself. It doesn't open immediately!

Comment: https://www.myjobs.com.mm can you check that? Service worker can control the start page URL from manifest.

Comment: Yes you're getting that particular error. Could you try setting your start URL to simply `/` instead of `./?utm_source=homescreen`?

Comment: yap, let me try and check. Btw, why you want me to remove `?utm_source=homescreen` instead of `/?utm_source=homescreen`

Comment: Because, as the error states 'no matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, **or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest**'

Comment: thanks a lot for clearifying. My failure was to use an absolute path in start_url. After I've changed it to relative path, it works well.

Comment: I must say that I need to remove the "porpuse": "maskable | any" from the 144x144 icon for it to work

Answer (score 5):

your manifest.json seems good enough. 
and the above mentioned points by @Extricate are correct and perfect.

So the next question is have you implemented service-worker for your app?
I read somewhere that an empty service-worker file would work but when I tried an empty implementation of service-worker, it said that

```
 'Site cannot be installed: the page does not work offline'
```

So I suppose that latest chrome version would not be supporting the A2HS prompt for APP INSTALL BANNERS if you service-worker dont support offline working.

You can try going to [Basic web app prompt](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/app-install-banner/basic-banner/index.html) , go to devtools in chrome, navigate to Application tab. 
There you will find manifest.json. On LHS of the manifest file, you can see the ADD TO HOME SCREEN. When you click, it will print

```
 'Site cannot be installed: the page does not work offline'
```

[PFA screenshot for same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPeAs.png)

Comment: same issue with me, not able to test add to the home screen in localhost.

Comment: "So I suppose that latest chrome version would not be supporting the A2HS prompt for APP INSTALL BANNERS if you service-worker dont support offline working." - this is not correct, at least at in July 2020.

Answer (score 5):

In your service worker js file add this one line of code:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {});
```

Answer (score 4):

May be usefull, as had similar issue. The Install infobar  appeared once and never again.

From [Developers Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native)

> The mini-infobar will appear when the site meets the criteria, and
>   once dismissed by the user, it will not appear again until a
>   sufficient amount of time has passed (currently 3 months).